# Django - template form checkbox

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am using Django 1.5. Suppose I have a view located at address: `example.com/page/*value*` I pass the value to the template in the context.
I want to have a checkbox, that will control the `*value*`
So for example I go to `example.com/page/5`
and the checkbox will then look like this:

- 0
- 5 (checked)
- 10

I select 10, click on the button, it redirects me to `/page/10`

In AngularJS I had `ng-model` for the value and it wasn't generally a problem, but what's the Django way of doing a similar thing?

Is it even possible by means of Django templates and pure HTML or do I have to write a bit of javascript?

I currently have it as a dropdown:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
  <li class="dropdown-header">Chosen: {{value}}</li>
  ...options...
</ul>
```

`<select>` works too, but I cant, quite figure out how to show a value by default:

```
<select>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use `<select>` and optionally set `selected` parameter of `<option>` with Django `{% ifequal a b %}` syntax:

```
<select>
  <option {% ifequal value 0 %} selected {% endifequal %}> 0 </option>
  <option {% ifequal value 5 %} selected {% endifequal %}> 5 </option>
  <option {% ifequal value 10 %} selected {% endifequal %}> 10 </option>
</select>
```

Similarly you would do checkbox by setting `checked` parameter

```
<input type='checkbox' {% ifequal value 0 %}checked{% endifequal %}> 0
....
```

Comment: The [`ifequal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal-and-ifnotequal) tag is obsolete, it's recommended to use the if tag instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you are rendering the select box manually, you just need to add the [`selected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Examples) attribute

```
<select>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="5" selected>5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

In a Django template, if `value` is in the template context, you can use an if tag to add the attribute.

```
<select>
  <option value="0" {% if value == 0 %}selected{% endif %}>0</option>
  <option value="5" {% if value == 5 %}selected{% endif %}>5</option>
  <option value="10" {% if value == 10 %}selected{% endif %}>10</option>
</select>
```

However, manually rendering templates is often a bad idea. You should consider using [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/) where possible, as they help automate validating input and html rendering of form fields.

Redirecting to a new page when an option is selected is a task for JavaScript, not Django.

Comment: I guess you have to use ifequal.... It was complaining at yours: Could not parse the remainder: '=="

Comment: Make sure you've got the spacing correct. For example, it must be `{% if x == 0 %}`, not `{% if x==0 %}`. You shouldn't use `ifequal`, it's obsolete. Using [`==`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#operator) in the if tag definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use form to do the task, simple example:

```
from django import forms

class SelectionForm(forms.Form):
    page = forms.ChoiceField(label="Your label", choices=((0, '0'), (5, '5'), (10, '10)) required=True)
```

And your view:

```
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class SelectionView(FormView):
    form_class = SelectionForm
    template_name = "your/template.html"

    def get_initial(self):
        return {'page': self.kwargs['page']}

    def form_valid(self, form):

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('selection-view', kwargs={'page': form.cleaned_data['page']})
```

In urls.py you should have numeric param somewhere in your url, called 'page'. Rendering form in template is up to you, also submitting form when select is changed.